# Changing the ringing volume when pressing volume keys

Tags: volume-control, htc-wildfire-s

The volume buttons of the HTC Wildfire S only changes the media volume, rather than ringing volume, even though I'm on the home screen.

Is there any way of changing the ringing volume when I click the volume buttons?

Comment: restarting the phone will do the job !

Answer (score 0):

You probably played a game or something and didn't close it correctly. You probably just pressed the home screen.

So, just restart it, or go back and close it properly.

Comment: Please use the full word next time (e.g. you, instead of just the letter u). Text-speak is frowned upon here.